# Why is $tan^{-1}\left(\frac{100}{100}\right)\neq90^\circ$ when it's said to have a slope of $100\%$?

Tags: trigonometry

I don't see why, but I "know" $tan^{-1}\left(\frac{100}{100}\right)=45^\circ$. It's not immediately intuitive for me if we think of it as driving a car on a road with 45 degree angle uphill, and then it's said to be a 100% slope?

Comment: @Eff If you drive a car on a road with 45 degree angle then its a 100% slope?

Comment: [Slope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) is *"the ratio of the vertical change to the horizontal change"*

Comment: @MartinR Yes, isn't it the correct term to use? Please see my comment to Eff

Comment: The percentage that is used to indicate slope is the percentage of vertical change vs horizontal change. If it's $100~\%$, it means that the horizontal and vertical change by the same amount. If it's $50~\%$, it means that the vertical change is half of the horizontal change.

Comment: A slope of $100\%$ is $1:1$ whereas $90\deg$ is $0:1$

Comment: The problem comes in when you confuse **inclination** with **slope**. Yes, the maximum inclination of a line wrt to the horizontal line is $90°$, but inclination is different from slope. The slope, or, more preferably, to avoid the easy confusion here, the gradient of a straight line compared to the horizontal is the ratio of rise to run when moving along the line. That is, the gradient tells us how much you've climbed above the horizontal for each unit distance along the horizontal. With this in mind it is easy to see that gradients can be as large as we please, so that there is no maximal...

Comment: ...gradient. If gradients are expressed as percentages, then we can have gradients of $2000\%$, say, and any value whatsoever, no matter how large. So a gradient of $100\%$ is not the maximal gradient. **Speaking loosely,** the maximal gradient is when the line is orthogonal to the horizontal, as you intuited, but the gradient here is $\infty\%$, *speaking very, very loosely.* So the line with $100 \%$ gradient is just midway between horizontal and vertical, so that you move up one unit for every unit step along that line. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: I see you've edited your post. A line at $45°$ to the horizontal doesn't have $100\%$ inclination. It only has a gradient (or slope, in some quarters) of $100\%$. The vertical line is the one with maximal inclination. Perhaps the main problem here seems to be that you think $100\%$ always means **all there is**, but that is not true in general. So whereas the maximal inclination is $90°$, there is strictly speaking no maximal gradient corresponding to this inclination.

Comment: @Eff You comment that you don't understand, but you don't comment about what? Why? Your comment is unproductive.

Comment: @Eff Still waiting...

Comment: @Eff And still waiting... You don't understand what? About my basic question regarding Arcus tan?

Comment: @MartinR There is nothing unclear about my question unless you don't know basic Maths. You're not obliged to comment if you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Eff  You're not obliged to comment if you don't know what you're talking about

Comment: It's hopeless. My last day on this forum, and I'm glad. You actually don't know basic Maths.

Comment: Are you referring to someone specific?  If so then it is silly to storm off a site because you don't like one person.  If you are referring to the community as a whole then it is pretty ridiculous.  There are clearly many here who know the subject very well.

Comment: Those who dont have the privilege of putting the post on hold, there is absolutely nothing unclear about my question, and i also got a excellent answer

Comment: @ReducedGosling I don't know why I have been called upon at least 5 (?) times. I have been gone. I defintely don't understand, because you've gotten a satisfactory answer. Isn't that about it? (When I voted, the question very different.)

Comment: When I commented at first, I simply did not understand what the was being asked. If you want to frame it as me 'not understanding basic mathematics', that's fine. The amazing thing was that I commented to make you know that, perhaps, people wouldn't understand the question. I gave you a chance to update your question to clarify the question. I didn't even vote. I commented for your sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have a line $y = ax + b$. Then, if we look at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on that line, and at another point $(x_0+\Delta x, y_0+\Delta y)$ on that line, we have that $$y_0 + \Delta y = a(x_0 + \Delta x) = ax_0 + a\Delta x = y_0 + a\Delta x \implies a = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.$$

Graphically, we are considering right triangle

[image]

so, $a = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \tan\alpha$.

Now, if $a = 100\% = 1$, then $\Delta x = \Delta y$. So, our right triangle is isosceles. It follows that $\alpha = 45^\circ$.

Comment: I really like this answer, I have printed it on paper. Your answer made me reconsider a lot of other things I thought I understood.

Answer (score 1):

It could just as well have been. But whoever decided on the standard we use today decided that it shouldn't be. Slope is defined as the ratio of vertical distance to horizontal distance, not the ratio of vertical distance to distance along the slope (i.e. the $\tan$ of the angle, not the $\sin$), and that's just the way it is. This means it's entirely possible to have slopes of $200\%$, and a completely vertical wall has infinite slope.

Note that this way it actually coincides with the notion of slope from calculus, where a $45^\circ$ line (given, for instance, by $y = x$) is said to have slope $1 = 100\%$.